# Can't save flow that creates/updates HealthcareProvider records

Tags: visual-workflow, health-cloud

I needed to fix an issue with a flow that makes changes to Healthcare Provider records.  The org has Health Cloud in it.  While I can save the flow, I can't activate it because of these errors:

- Create_Healthcare_Provider_Record (Create Records) - The object "HealthcareProvider" can't be created through a flow.
- Update_Healthcare_Provider_Recordasdf (Update Records) - The object "HealthcareProvider" can't be updated through a flow.
- Update_Past_Provider_History_Records (Update Records) - The object "HealthcareProvider" can't be updated through a flow.

The flow was last modified on 2/13/2024, so I'm wondering if there was a recent change to Health Cloud that is causing this issue.  I Googled the error but couldn't find anything.  Is there a way around this issue besides removing the functionality that is now problematic.